# Vue: How to build bundle for Nuxt with vue-cli-service?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-cli

A user tries to use [my package](https://github.com/avidofood/vue-responsive-video-background-player/issues/8) for nuxt.js, but gets the error: `document is not defined`.

I found the first issue. When I build the bundle with `"build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name index ./src/index.js"`,
`vue-style-loader` is being used. This, however, results in the error for using nuxt projects. This part is failing:

```
function addStyle (obj /* StyleObjectPart */) {
  var update, remove
  var styleElement = document.querySelector('style[' + ssrIdKey + '~="' + obj.id + '"]')
```

Document is not defined since we are using server rendering. But the question is how can I build up my package so that I can use it with nuxt?

I need:

- index.common.js
- index.umd.js
- index.umd.min.js

Comment: Im having the same issue - had any luck

Comment: @Jujubes no luck :( if you find a solution, don't be shy to post it here, please!

Comment: i havent found anything yet - spent hours playing around with config files and searching the internet without any success

Comment: added bounty - hopefully that works

Comment: Have you tried inlining the CSS via `css: { extract: false }` in your vue.config.js? As the "error" is coming from extracting the styles, that might be a decent workaround

Comment: User `rollup` it accomplished the conversion for me. now i just need to tweak it so i do not have their folder structure. the cli does a nice job of compiling everything for a brand new vue repo which you can amend(rollup.config.js) to make it perfect

Comment: @Jujubes when I find the time I have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the server-side rendering. If you need to specify that you want to import a resource only on the client-side, you need to use the `process.client` variable.

For example, in your `.vue` file:

```js
if (process.client) {
  require('external_library')
  // do something
}
```

The above is the fundamental solution to `document is not defined`.

I checked some information and found that, this problem is not caused by your package. In fact, the problem lies on the `cache-loader` package in the user’s nuxt project.
For some reason cache-loader incorrectly determined the current environment as `browser` and not `node` so that `vue-style-loader` is confused and used client implementation instead.

So try to let users add the following configuration to the `nuxt.config.js` file to disable stylesheet caches on server-side:

```js
build: {
 ...
 cache: true,
 extend(config, { isServer, isDev, isClient }) {
   ...
   if (isServer) {
     for (const rules of config.module.rules.filter(({ test }) =>
       /\.((c|le|sa|sc)ss|styl.*)/.test(test.toString())
     )) {
       for (const rule of rules.oneOf || []) {
         rule.use = rule.use.filter(
           ({ loader }) => loader !== 'cache-loader'
         )
       }
     }
   }
   ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer

Comment: read the questions and the comment - please do not copy and paste stuff which is readily available online

Comment: the question is how to is Vue: How to build bundle for Nuxt with vue-cli-service?`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but it is not using the `vue-cli` service. Instead, the files are compiled by `rollup`. I found using the [`cli`](https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup) service much easier. The only problem with the `cli` service is it will adjust the "flow" of your repo. However, you can modify the `rollup.config.js` to amend the folder structure.

The problem with rollup is that it isn't webpack. Therefore, all components using a webpack configuration need to be adjusted or rollup.config.js needs to be amended to include the additional functionality

Comment: The documentation for `rollup` is nowhere near `webpack` either. I also found that using the `sfc-init` method will bring in outdated packages. I would update after